How do I write a generic type hint for a Python method for a decorator function?
I created a Python decorator that works great on functions.  It allows a function to be called directly or executed from a thread.  I would like to use it on methods as well but this results in an error when mypy checks my usage.
Here's what the decorator looks like:
from typing import Callable, Generic, TypeVar, ParamSpec
from functools import wraps
from threading import Thread

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

class CallOrThreadFunction(Generic[P, R]):
    def __init__(self,
                 start_thread: Callable[P, Thread],
                 call: Callable[P, R]):
        self.start_thread = start_thread
        self.call = call
        
def call_or_start_thread(function: Callable[P, R]) -> CallOrThreadFunction[P, R]:
    @wraps(function)
    def start_thread(*args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        thread = Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        return Thread

    return CallOrThreadFunction(start_thread, function)

Here's an example use of it on a method:
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    @call_or_start_thread
    def my_method(self, parameter: int = 1):
        print(f'name: {self.name} parameter: {parameter}')


adrian = Employee('Adrian')
adrian.my_method.start_thread(5)

MyPy reports an error from that last line:
Argument 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Employee"
The problem seems to be that when the decorator is applied to the method, the "self" method is included in P.  When I invoke the method, however, self has already been combined into "adrian.my_method".
MyPy does not report an error for this version
Employee.my_method.start_thread(adrian, 5)

But I'm trying to figure out if the generic type hints can be written in a way that will work with a standard method call
adrian.my_method.start_thread(5)


The problem is you need the ‘self’ parameter, but that is not available statically, when you decorate the method.  You could explicitly pass the parameter. Another way to do this would be to define ‘my_method’ at runtime, i.e., in the constructor: ‘self.my_method = call_or_start_thread(self._my_method)’ where the private version has the same body but no decorator

That works great as an alternative solution.  Perhaps I've just bumping up against the limit of what can be done with type hints and decorators in 3.11

First check if the logic actually works, aside from satisfying the type checker, by unit-testing it. I think it might not, because of what @Razumov noted - at the time that the decorator is applied, the method is just a function, and self is an ordinary parameter, and the thread is spawned using that unbound function. (Maybe it still gets the needed parameter from *args when the thread actually starts.) Consider writing a separate version of the decorator for methods.

I considered writing a separate decorator for methods.  I was unable to figure out how to write one that would allow mypy to correctly check the parameters.

I don't think there's actually anything wrong with the typing.  As a sanity check, does adrian.my_method.start_thread(adrian, 5) type check? It should, this being the explicit passing option I mentioned.

This took a lot of playing around, and my problem is a bit different, however I was able to get a decorator that applies to class methods and instance methods and preserves the types for callers and for typing with mypy.
The key step is the attibute .__get__ allows us to get the runtime callchain to see if we are a class or instance method. Because the MethodAttribute has it's generics specified by the decorator, the types work. And during run time it switches to the correct implementation.
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Callable, Generic, Type, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec, Concatenate


class Plugin:
    ...


I = ParamSpec("I") # Internal, includes self or cls
E = ParamSpec("E") # External, as seen by caller
R = TypeVar("R") # Return type
P = TypeVar("P", bound=Plugin)



class PluginMethod(Generic[E, R]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[E, R]):
        self.func = func
        self.name = func.__name__

    def __call__(self, *args: E.args, **kwargs: E.kwargs) -> R:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)



class MethodAttribute(Generic[I, E, R]):
    name: str

    def __init__(self, func: Callable[I, R]):
        self.func = func

    def __set_name__(self, owner: Type[Plugin], name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance: Plugin | None, owner: Type[Plugin]) -> PluginMethod[E, R]:
        if instance is None:
            def cls_method(*args: E.args, **kwargs: E.kwargs) -> R:
                return self.func.__func__(owner, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
            cls_method.__name__ = self.name
            return PluginMethod(cls_method)
        
        def method(*args: E.args, **kwargs: E.kwargs) -> R:
            return self.func(instance, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
        method.__name__ = self.name
        return PluginMethod(method)



class Lib:
    @staticmethod
    def method() -> Callable[[Callable[Concatenate[P, E], R]],   MethodAttribute[Concatenate[P, E], E, R]]:
        def decorations(func: Callable[Concatenate[P, E], R]) -> MethodAttribute[Concatenate[P, E], E, R]:
            return MethodAttribute[Concatenate[P, E], E, R](func)
        return decorations

    @staticmethod
    def cls_method() -> Callable[[Callable[Concatenate[Type[P], E], R]],   MethodAttribute[Concatenate[Type[P], E], E, R]]:
        def decorations(func:     Callable[Concatenate[Type[P], E], R]) -> MethodAttribute[Concatenate[Type[P], E], E, R]:
            return MethodAttribute[Concatenate[Type[P], E], E, R](func)
        return decorations


class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    @Lib.method()
    def start(self) -> None:
        print(f"INNER start({self})")

    @Lib.cls_method()
    @classmethod
    def dry_run(cls) -> str:
        print(f"INNER dry_run({cls})")
        return "dry run result"

    @Lib.method()
    def reprint(self, arg: int, k: str = "default") -> str:
        print(f"INNER reprint({self}, {arg}, {k})")
        return arg * k


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = MyPlugin()
    p.start()
    print(p.reprint(3, k="hello"))
    print(MyPlugin.dry_run())

